# How to update the state in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm using a reducer to set the state in Redux. My state currently looks something like this.

```
{
  activeConversation: "Jim"
  conversations: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  user: {id: 8, username: "josh", email: ""}
}
```

In my old reducer, I was just getting the conversations array and setting that but now I need access to the activeConversation string as well. Therefore, I decided to use my root reducer which combines everything so it can work correctly. Here's my root reducer.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import loggerMiddleware from "redux-logger";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";

import user from "./user";
import conversations from "./conversations";
import activeConversation from "./activeConversation";
import {
addMessageToStore,
} from "./utils/reducerFunctions";

const CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT = "CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT";
const SET_MESSAGE = "SET_MESSAGE";

export const clearOnLogout = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT
  };
};

export const setNewMessage = (message, sender) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MESSAGE,
    payload: { message, sender: sender || null },
  };
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  user,
  conversations,
  activeConversation
});
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === CLEAR_ON_LOGOUT) {
    state = undefined;
  } else if (action.type === SET_MESSAGE) {
    return addMessageToStore(state, action.payload);
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware));
```

My setNewMessage function is called which then calls `addMessageToStore`.

```
export const addMessageToStore = (state, payload) => {
  const { message, sender } = payload;
  return { ...state, conversations: state.conversations.map((convo) => {
    if (convo.id === message.conversationId) {
      const newUnread = convo.unreadMessages;
      if (state.activeConversation === convo.otherUser) {
        newUnread = (parseInt(newUnread) + 1).toString();
      }
      const newConvo = {
        ...convo,
        messages: convo.messages.concat(message),
        latestMessageText: convo.latestMessageText,
        unreadMessages: newUnread
      }
      console.log("newConvo:", {...state, conversations: newConvo});
      return {...state, conversations: newConvo};
    } else {
      return {...state, conversations: convo};
    }
  })};
};
```

The problem with this is that `next state` isn't being updated. When it returns `next state`, it just shows the previous state instead of my new one. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are "cutting" your state slices inefficiently. At best, a Reducer should always own their own state, and you are right now going to great lengths to have a meta-reducer for `conversations` to have access to the `activeConversation`.

Why not have a normal reducer for both?

Have a state of the shape

```
{
  user,
  conversations
}
```

where `conversations` has the shape

```
{
  items,
  active
}
```

That way your `conversations` reducer has just access to it's own state properties - `items` and `active`  - and does not need to to any gymnastics.

Comment: Also, please take a look at the official Redux documentation - you are generally writing a very old style of Redux here. Modern Redux is about a fourth of the code you are writing here and much more comfortable to use. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: I actually do have a reducer for both conversations and activeConversation but the problem is that I have no idea how to get the value of activeConversation in my conversations reducer.

Comment: That is why I mean "put both in the same reducer". A reducer can contain as little or as much data as you want - and obviously that data is interconnected, so splitting it into multiple reducers is only going to give you a headache.

The Redux docs suggest one reducer slice per feature, not per single data value. Having only atomic data would make Reducers pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it has to do with:

```
return { ...state, conversations: state.conversations.map((convo) => {
    // ...
        return {...state, conversations: newConvo};
    } else {
        return {...state, conversations: convo};
    }
 }
```

Where for *each* conversation you are ending up with a clone of the entire state, but with the `conversations` key swapped out for a single conversation (e.g. `{state: { conversations: [ { state: { conversations: convo } } ] }`)

You should be doing

```
 return { ...state, conversations: state.conversations.map((convo) => {
    // ...
        return newConvo;
    } else {
        return convo;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work. Before, my return statement used to say ```return state.conversations.map``` but that caused quite alot of problems with ```next state``` being set to just the conversations array as opposed to the entire state.

Comment: You are completely missing what I am saying.  Your *top* level return includes the rest of the state.  Right now you are *also* including it in the return from your map function.